# Add space between div columns with rows of equal height

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Is there a way to add some space between the div with `H3-1` and the div containing `H3-2`.

- Without using custom `CSS` would be preferable but it is not necessary.
- If possible, I would like to keep `col-sm-6` because using `col-sm-5` and `offset` adds more space than what I want.
- The `ml-auto` and `mr-auto` is also important because sometimes there can be odd number of columns (which comes in dynamically) and it needs to be centered.

```css
@import url(https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css);
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row row-eq-height">
    <div class="col-sm-6 border align-top ml-auto mr-auto mt-3 bg-light">
      <div class="m-0 p-2">
        <h3>H3-1</h3>
        <p>sad ajsdha sjhd ajshdjashd jashdj ashdj ashd jashd jashdj ashdj ashdj ashdj ashdjas dashdj asdhjashd ashd as</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 border align-top ml-auto mr-auto mt-3 bg-light">
      <div class="m-0 p-2">
        <h3>H3-2</h3>
        <p>asjd asjdh asjdhasj hasjdh jshd jashjas dh jasdha jdh jashdj ashdj shdj ashdj </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 border align-top ml-auto mr-auto mt-3 bg-light">
      <div class="m-0">
        <h3>H3-3</h3>
        <p>asd asd asd a</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Not relevant anymore] Yes, for example, by changing column classes from `col-sm-6` to `col-sm-5` and adding `col-md-offset-2` class to second column:

[Edited example to reflect edits in question: ]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">

<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<div class="container">
<div class="row row-eq-height">
    <div class="col-sm-6  align-top ml-auto mr-auto mt-3 pl-1 pr-1">
        <div class="h-100 bg-light border m-0 p-2 pl-4 pr-4">
            <h3>H3-1</h3>
            <p>sad ajsdha sjhd ajshdjashd jashdj ashdj ashd jashd jashdj ashdj ashdj ashdj ashdjas dashdj asdhjashd ashd as</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 align-top ml-auto mr-auto mt-3 pl-1 pr-1">
        <div class="h-100 bg-light border m-0 p-2 pl-4 pr-4">
            <h3>H3-2</h3>
            <p>asjd asjdh asjdhasj hasjdh jshd jashjas dh jasdha jdh jashdj ashdj shdj ashdj </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 align-top ml-auto mr-auto mt-3 pl-1 pr-1">
         <div class="h-100 bg-light border m-0 p-2 pl-4 pr-4">
             <h3>H3-3</h3>
             <p>asjd asjdh asjdhasj hasjdh jshd jashjas dh jasdha jdh jashdj ashdj shdj ashdj </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you are not able to add custom CSS but I managed to add some space using bootstrap 4's flex layouts.

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<div class="container">
<div class="flex-row row-eq-height d-inline-flex">
    <div class="col-sm-6 border align-top mt-3 bg-light mr-2">
        <div class="m-0 p-2">
            <h3>H3-1</h3>
            <p>sad ajsdha sjhd ajshdjashd jashdj ashdj ashd jashd jashdj ashdj ashdj ashdj ashdjas dashdj asdhjashd ashd as</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 border align-top mt-3 bg-light ml-2">
        <div class="m-0 p-2">
            <h3>H3-2</h3>
            <p>asjd asjdh asjdhasj hasjdh jshd jashjas dh jasdha jdh jashdj ashdj shdj ashdj </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

you can increase/decrease mr-2/ml-2 to increase the left and right margins on your bootstrap columns as you see fit

Answer (score 0):

```css
@import url(https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css);
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row row-eq-height">
    <div class="col-sm-6 align-top ml-auto mr-auto mt-3 p-0">
      <div class="border border-primary rounded ml-1 mr-1 h-100 p-2 bg-light">
        <h3>H3-1</h3>
        <p>sad ajsdha sjhd ajshdjashd jashdj ashdj ashd jashd jashdj ashdj ashdj ashdj ashdjas dashdj asdhjashd ashd as</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 align-top ml-auto mr-auto mt-3 p-0">
      <div class="border border-primary rounded ml-1 mr-1 h-100 p-2 bg-light">
        <h3>H3-2</h3>
        <p>asjd asjdh asjdhasj hasjdh jshd jashjas dh jasdha jdh jashdj ashdj shdj ashdj </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 align-top ml-auto mr-auto mt-3 p-0">
      <div class="border border-primary rounded ml-1 mr-1 h-100 p-2 bg-light">
        <h3>H3-3</h3>
        <p>asd asd asd a</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```